# Retrieving many-to-many results from GORM

Tags: mysql, database, go, go-gorm

I am mapping my database using [gorm](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm).

I have two tables (`service` and `resource`) with a many-to-many relationship. I am modelling them in code as such:

```
type Service struct {
    BaseModel
    Name      string     `gorm:"not null;unique_index"`
    Resources []Resource `gorm:"many2many:service_resource"`
}

type Resource struct {
    BaseModel
    Name string `gorm:"not null;unique_index"`
}
```

Using gorm's [AutoMigrate](https://godoc.org/github.com/jinzhu/gorm#DB.AutoMigrate) the following tables are created:

[image: Database diagram m2m]

(I also executed a raw SQL query to add the id primary key in the mapping table.)

To create a new service, I use the following code:

```
service := Service{
    Name: "core",
    Resources: []Resource{
        {Name: "ec2"},
        {Name: "dynamo"},
    },
}
db.Create(&service)
```

This creates all the resources along with the service and fills in the relationship between them in the `service_resource` table just fine, as expected.

However, my problem is when I'm querying for the services. I use the following code to retrieve all services:

```
services := []model.Service{}
db.Find(&services)
```

This returns successfully with the services array populated, but the `Resources` array of each service is empty:

```
"services": [
    {
        "ID": 1,
        "Name": "core",
        "Resources": null
    },
    ...
]
```

I was under the assumption that gorm would populate it automatically. Is there some step that I'm missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to [Preload](https://godoc.org/github.com/jinzhu/gorm#DB.Preload) the resources field before querying for services:

```
services := []model.Service{}
db.Preload("Resources").Find(&services) // error checking ommited
```

This correctly populates the `Resources` field of every service.

Comment: This is very bad advice! `Preload` will result in an "in" statement that takes into account all primary keys from the "services" table. Following the growth of records in the "services" table, the "preload" query "in" clause will contain more and more ids degrading its performance.